# How do I change atom-runner path for Ruby when Ruby is installed on Ubuntu in Windows 10?

Tags: ruby, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux, atom-runner

I'm trying to use atom-runner plugin in Atom text editor. My Ruby is installed in Ubuntu (through Windows store). When I try to run script in Atom I get this error: [Are you sure path is configured correctly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po9vi.jpg)
I understand I need to change the path but how do I do that when Ruby is installed in Ubuntu bash?

Comment: Why are you installing Atom through Windows store, and not natively on Ubuntu?

Comment: I Installed Ubuntu through Windows store. Are you suggesting that I uninstall Atom then reinstall inside of Ubuntu Application?